# Bitcoin QT encryption / passphrase

Tags: bitcoin-core, passphrase

Installed the Bitcoin QT client only last week... synchronised it with the blockchain... and sent my bitcoins to this adress...
Now, when I want to send to some other address, it asks for the passphrase. However, have never had the option of providing a passphrase. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

> However, have never had the option of providing a passphrase.

You must certainly have set a passphrase in the past. There's no way to remove it without knowing exactly what it is. If you can not recall what password you set, your funds are lost.

Comment: Installed the client only last week... synchronised it with the blockchain... that is all